# Swift Get value from function

Tags: swift, class, static, var

I have two class and i would like to get a variable with the value (the variable is in a function) to my second class :

```
public class StreamPlayer {

    class var sharedInstance : StreamPlayer{
        struct Static {
            static let instance : StreamPlayer = StreamPlayer()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    public var intermediate = NSString()

    func metaDataUpdated(metaData : NSString){
        var result : String = ""
        var listItems = metaData.componentsSeparatedByString(";") as [String]
        if (listItems.count > 0){
            var containerName = listItems[0]
            result =  "StreamTitle=\'([^\"]*)\'".matchesForRegexIn(containerName, atRangeIndex: 1)

            self.intermediate = result
        }

   }
}
```

and the second class

```
class RadioViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println(test + StreamPlayer.sharedInstance.intermediate)
     }
}
```

The problem is that the var intermediate doesn't change and don't get the value of result (in my first class)

Comment: Did you makes sure that listItems.count > 0?

Comment: You never call the function `metaDataUpdated`.

Comment: yes i already println result and it get what i want, the problem is to stock result into intermediate,

Comment: metaDataUpdated is using by another function

Comment: Did you make sure if result has value?

Comment: yes i checked it (sorry for my english if i make some mistakes)

Comment: Also your class instance is shared. Maybe the same instance gets updated by different parts of your code. What you posted is not enough to determine the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've copied your StreamPlayer class code into a playground. I've just commented out the  *matchesForRegexIn* method as it seems it's your String extension so my code looks like this:

```
public class StreamPlayer {

  class var sharedInstance : StreamPlayer{
    struct Static {
      static let instance : StreamPlayer = StreamPlayer()
    }
    return Static.instance
  }

  public var intermediate = String()

  func metaDataUpdated(metaData : NSString){
    var result : String = ""
    let listItems = metaData.componentsSeparatedByString(";") as [String]
    if (listItems.count > 0){
      // var containerName = listItems[0]
      result = "StreamTitle=\'([^\"]*)\'" //.matchesForRegexIn(containerName, atRangeIndex: 1)
      intermediate = result
    } 
  }
}

// calling the method to make sure intermediate gets updated
StreamPlayer.sharedInstance.metaDataUpdated("asd")
// check if it got updated
print(StreamPlayer.sharedInstance.intermediate)
```

The last line prints *StreamTitle=\'([^\"]*)\'* so all is good. Just make sure to call *StreamPlayer.sharedInstance.metaDataUpdated* before checking *intermediate*

PS. I'm really not sure what you're trying to achieve by sharing intermediate results from a function to the outside world but it feels off. Think about splitting *metaDataUpdated* method into two methods maybe?

PPS. metaDataUpdated is a really bad name for a function

PPPS. If I were you I'd declare intermediate as String?

Answer (score 0):

self.intermediate is a NSString while result is a String

Try

```
self.intermediate = result as NSString
```